# why "colspan" does not work in my table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have made a simple table form [here in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Yb2L/5/).

I also put my code here:

```
<table>
     <tr>
        <td class="field_label">name</td>
        <td>*</td>
        <td>
         <input type="text">
        </td>
        <td>
         <input type="text">
        </td>

      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>email</td>
        <td>*</td>
        <td colspan="2">
           <input type="text"> 
        </td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

Two questions:

**1.** As you see, I use `colspan="2"` in `email` input field `<td>` to make the text field length the same as `name` fields which occupy two columns, but it does not work, why?

**2.** How can I set default value in the input field and set default value color to be gray ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding question **1.**: The column holding the input for the second table row will be 2 columns long (as you could see if you were showing borders for the table columns); however, input fields have a default width in every browser - meaning that the input will show at exactly the same width as the one input above; that's why you probably think `colspan` isn't working.

Add a `size` attribute to the `input` tag, or a `width` css property, e.g. like this:

```
<table>
 <tr>
    <td class="field_label">name</td>
    <td>*</td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>email</td>
    <td>*</td>
    <td colspan="2"><input type="text" style="width:99%;" ></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

As for **2.**, the default value of an input can be set by using the `value` attribute:

```
<input type="text" name="ID" value="101" />
```

As shown in the example, you should also use at least the `name` attribute (to be able to reference the input from JavaScript or PHP); and to make it html5 valid, you should close the tag with `/>` (since you don't have a separate closing `</input>` tag).

Changing the text color can be done by adding CSS styles; either in the input itself, or via the `id` or `class` attributes; the following would e.g. make the text color in the input light gray:

```
<input type="text" style="color:#CCC;" >
```

Be sure to check out how to specify CSS styles in general (e.g. [inline](http://www.tizag.com/cssT/inline.php), or by [id or class](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_id_class.asp)), and [how to specify colors with CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#CSS_colors).

Answer (score 4):

Setting the `style` to `display:block` will also defeat the `colspan` attribute.

Set the `style` to `display:table-cell` instead, or don't set the `display` style.

Answer (score 1):

Is [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aUajP/1/) what you want to do?

- Actually, it worked but didn't get displayed because your width
  wasn't `100%`.
- To add default text in an input value, you can use the `value` property of your input, for instance: `<input type="text" value="Default text">`
- You can style an input box like any other element, for instance: `<input type="text" style="color: #FFFFFF; background-color: #C0C0C0;">`

Answer (score 0):

**2. How can I set default value in the input field and set default value color to be gray ?**

```
<input type="text" value=2> -- for setting default value
<TD bgcolor=##030303> --- For coloring
```